# How do I style the round videojs scrubber slider button

Tags: css, video.js, skin

I'm looking for suggestions on how to style the round videojs scrubber button control.  All I've been able to figure out looking at a video defauult css skin is:

```
.video-js .vjs-play-progress:before {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.5em;
    top: -0.3333333333em;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:#eb882a;  <- setting the color here
}
```

This does put an oragnish square around the round scrubber slider control but doesn't change the color of the round slider scrubber control.

```
.video-js .vjs-play-progress {
    background-color:#eb882a;  <- setting the color here
}
```

Just changes the color of the progress line before the round scrubber slider control.

How can I change the color of the round scrubber control itself which remains white?

Answer (score 0):

The slider handle is a character from an icon font, so use `color` rather than `background-color`.